# arrange data from associated array

Tags: php

I have an associated array of result. I need to group the array with respect to their categories. For example: The jobs related to category will be combined under single iteration.

Code using to make it:

```
    $result = array();
    foreach ($group as $element) {
        $result[$element['category']][] = $element;
    }
```

```
[Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt
                    [jobs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 12/11/2019
                                    [country] => IND
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt
                    [jobs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 02/11/2019
                                    [country] => US
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 03/11/2019
                                    [country] => SS
                                )
                        )
                )
      )
```

But i need data like:

```
[Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt
                    [jobs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 12/11/2019
                                    [country] => IND
                                )
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 02/11/2019
                                    [country] => US
                                )
                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 03/11/2019
                                    [country] => SS
                                )
                        )
                )
      )
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this `$result[$element['category']][] = $element;` you are just appending each element with the same category to an array. What you want instead is to merge them. So, while constructing `$result` you need to handle two cases: If the `$result`-array does not contain a category you call `$result[$element['category']] = $element;`. And if it already contains the category you append the `$element['jobs']`-array to `$result[$element['category']]['jobs']`.

Have a look at `array_key_exists` ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php)) and `array_merge` ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php)). You can use them like this for your case:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($group as $element) {
    if(array_key_exists($element['category'], $result)) {
        $result[$element['category']]['jobs'] = array_merge($result[$element['category']]['jobs'], $element['jobs']);
    }
    else {
        $result[$element['category']] = $element;
    }
}
```

Note: This does **not** result in the exact structure you specified in your question. In your question you specified that `$result` should be an array with numerical indicies for each category (i.e. `$result[0]` and so on). In my solution you have alphanumerical keys, i.e. `$result['Professional Services / Consulting / Project Mgmt']`. But I thought that the latter is what you actually wanted.

Comment: I tried the above solution with this `$result[$element['category']]['jobs'] = $element;`. But it is combining the results with more than one array results but omitting a single result array.

Comment: This `$result[$element['category']]['jobs'] = $element` would not append to but override `$result[$element['category']]['jobs']`. Have a look at the functions I mentioned.

Comment: In the end, I will have a single $result array. So how I can run the `array_merge` function. Can you please edit your answer and guide me a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: You are an awesome brother! Really appreciate your help. Thank you soo much.

Comment: You're welcome. However, check the note I added to my solution.

Comment: Yeah. Actually, $result contains the self-created associated array based on two keys as `category` and `jobs`. I just need to combine the jobs data by grouping the similar category wise.

Comment: So, to be sure, the provided solution is in fact what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. This is the one needed. Very happy with your answer. Thank you again.